# Differential amplifier, superposition theorem, output derivation, what is a loop here?

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, superposition

So based on [this](https://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/the-differential-amplifier-transfer-function/) article, when V1 is removed/grounded, in this picture.

Is the loop number 1 drawn correctly? Or does R3 and R4 both belong to the same loop? I'm not sure how Vout2 was calculated. It's supposed to be: \$ -V2 \frac{R4}{R3} \$

[image]

Comment: This is an inverting amplifier, there are copious web sites that explain how this works, including this one. When the current flows through R3 and arrives at the node, it has the choice of flowing through R4 or flowing through free space ...

Comment: I guess you want to find a current loop to use Kirchoff's voltage law to solve the circuit. One of the needed loops contains the source of V2, R3, R4 and the internal controlled output voltage source in the opamp. The loop starts and ends at GND. If you reach the conceptual feedback loop to handle this circuit as a control engineering style block diagram you must consider R3 and R4 as attenuator for both Vout2 and V2 and also as a summing element for attenuated V2 and attenuated Vout2. Tricky, I say! As suggested get one of the numerous texts which present how the calculations can be done.

Comment: @user287001, Exactly! R3 and R4 form a resistor summer with weighted inputs. Travelling along the loop V1-R3-R4-Vout2, we can see that V1 and Vout2 are summed and the total voltage is applied to total resistance R3 + R4. Another observation is that Vout2 is equal to the voltage drop across R4 and neutralizes it; the result is a virtual ground at the inverting input. And finally, the op-amp output can be thought of as a "negative resistor" with resistance -R4 that neutralizes the positive resistance R4. The result is zero resistance (the network of the two resistors behaves as a piece of wire).

Comment: As @Chu and others have pointed out, I think this is question should be removed for being duplicate/ this is just asking how to get equation for transfer function of inverting amp. Also, the title is wrong, no "superposition theorem" is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Since V1 is grounded, the upper loop gives you the equation

$$ I_{top}R_1 = -I_{top}R_2 $$

which implies that the current in the upper loop is zero. Thus, the voltage at the *positive* input terminal  of the op-amp is 0 volts.

Therefore, the current on the bottom loop is

$$I_{bottom} = \frac{V_2 - 0}{R_3} = \frac{V_2}{R_3} $$

so by using by Ohm's law with resistor R4,

$$ \frac{0 - V_{out2}}{R_4} = \frac{-V_{out2}}{R_4} = I_{bottom}$$

so

$$V_{out2} = -\frac{R_4V_2}{R_3}$$

Comment: Good answer, although I think you should also include a small snippet as to why the loop they drew is wrong. I think Just point out that the loop must start and end at the same spot, and stopping at the virtual ground at (-v) is not good enough, that is, the current flows to actual ground, thus completing the loop

Answer (score 0):

> Is the loop number 1 drawn correctly?

No, this is not a loop; it is only a branch. The loop 1 includes V1, R3, R4 and Vout2 (it is closed by the ground). Since V- is 0 V, we can write Vout/Vin = -R4/R3; so Vout = -R4.Vin/R3.

Here are some interesting observations about this unique circuit of four elements.

R3 and R4 form a resistor summer with weighted inputs. Travelling along the loop of the four elements V1-R3-R4-Vout2, we can see that V1 and Vout2 are summed (+ -, + -) and the total voltage is applied to the total resistance of R3 + R4.

Another observation is that Vout2 is equal to the voltage drop across R4 and thus neutralizes it; the result is the well-known phenomenon of *virtual ground* at the inverting input. This is a unique property of all op-amp inverting circuits (see also [Voltage Compensation](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Voltage_Compensation)).

And finally, the op-amp output can be thought of as a "negative resistor" with resistance -R4 that neutralizes the positive resistance R4. The result is zero resistance; the network of the two resistors behaves as a piece of wire shunting the inverting input.

Comment: I think you meant to say the loop includes V2-R3-R4-Vout2